# makefile calling function inside a function

Tags: makefile

This might be a very basic but I need to call a function within a function but I cannot figure it out:

```
chmod-prod:

    chown git:git-R ./

composer-dev:

    [who do I how chmod-prod: within here]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `chmod-prod` and `composer-dev` are known as a targets in make terminology.

**Using targets**

If the result of `chmod-prod` needs to happen before the rest of the "recipe" in `composer-dev` then the most natural way in make would be to add it as a dependency.

```
composer-dev: chmod-prod
    [the rest of composer-dev recipe]
```

Given that both these targets do not lead to the creation of a file with their name it would be good practice to declare them as `.PHONY`:

```
.PHONY: chmod-prod
.PHONY: composer-dev
```

This ensures that the targets will not be affected if someone adds a file with the same name.

**Using a variable**

Another route would be store the command in a variable:

```
chmod_prod_cmd:=chown git:git-R ./
```

Which could then be used in the recipes of both your targets:

```
composer-dev:
    $(chmod_prod_cmd)

composer-dev:
    $(chmod_prod_cmd)
    [presumably some more recipe]
```

**Canning a multi-line recipe**

If the bit of recipe you want to reuse involves multiple lines then you will need to use the `define` directive instead of a normal variable assignment:

```
define chmod_prod_cmd
    echo Doing something
    chown git:git-R ./
endef
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and for a very detailed question. This was perfect and it hopes it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming those need to be targets (and they sequence that way) then PeterSW has the right answer.

If they need finer-grained sequencing *within* the body of the `composer-dev` recipe then you could always just run make again (e.g. `$(MAKE) chmod-prod`) though I wouldn't suggest this structure of makefiles as it is expensive (to say the least).

That being said if the recipe body of `chmod-prod` is actually just a simple single (or series) of shell commands (that don't need to be run externally manually i.e. as `make chmod-prod`) then using a make variable/`define` instead of a target.

Something like this

```
chmod-prod := chown git:git-R ./
```

or this

```
define chmod-prod
    chown git:git-R ./
endef
```

and used like this

```
composer-dev:
        some_command
        $(chmod-prod)
        other_command
```